# How to create and display music scores on Android

Tags: java, android, music-notation

I'm working on a simple app that explains the musical harmony foundamentals. I want to write programmatically some music scores and display it on a Canvas. I've found a Java library called abc4j ([See this](https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/january-2008-writing-music-in-java-two-approaches)), perfect for this job. The problem is that the Android porting of this library (called abc4android, [see this](https://github.com/grennis/abc4android)) remove, obviously, all desktop/UI code and dependencies and unfortunately the image output is obtained with an import of abc.ui.swing.JScoreComponent.
Is there a way to easily write and show (with an image or a music font) a music score in Android?

Comment: Can't see your image,please reedit your question.

Comment: @Aolphn I'm sorry! Now all the links work correctly. They aren't images, but only a link to an abc4j review and to the abc4android fork on GitHub.

Comment: The following view as image showed is what you want?https://github.com/Sciss/abc4j/blob/master/images/scoreEx.jpg?raw=true

Comment: @Aolphn yes! But in abc4android I can't obtain it because there isn't the class "JScoreComponent" and, consequently, the function `.writeScoreTo(new File("Score.jpg"))`